# Rails - default render streaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, streaming, render

Normally [Rails streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) requires:

```
render stream: true
```

in a controller action. Is there any way to make that the default for the whole controller? RailsCasts says it's possible with a [`stream` class method](http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming?view=asciicast):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  stream # doesn't work
  ...
end
```

but that's not in the official docs and on Rails 4.1, I get `undefined local variable or method`stream' for ApplicationController:Class`. It would be nice to be able to declare streaming in one place in order to keep actions DRY.

Comment: `class ApplicationController< ActionController::Base` did you use it? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6061c540ac7880233a6e32de85cec72c20ed8778/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was there. Added to the example above.

Comment: The default webserver in `Rails 3`, `WEBrick`, doesn’t support streaming so to see it in action we’ll need to switch to another that does, such as `Unicor`n.

The `Unicorn` gem is listed in the application’s `Gemfile` but it’s commented out by default. To use it we uncomment this line and then run `bundle` to install it.

Comment: Did you close with a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't proceed with streaming

Answer (score 0):

The default `webserver` in `Rails 3`,`WEBrick`, doesn’t support streaming so to see it in action we’ll need to switch to another that does, such as `Unicorn`. The `Unicorn` gem is listed in the application’s `Gemfile` but it’s commented out by default. To use it we uncomment this line and then run `bundle` to install it.

```
 gem 'unicorn'
```

Then

```
 $ bundle install
```

Unicorn supports streaming but it needs to be configured. For this, you

need to create a config file as follow:

```
 # unicorn.config.rb
  listen 3000, tcp_nopush: false
```

And use it on initialization:

```
  unicorn_rails --config-file unicorn.config.rb
```

You may also want to configure other parameters like `tcp_nodelay`.
   [Please check its documentation for more information:](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-listenhttp://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-listen)

If you are using Unicorn with `NGINX`, you may need to tweak `NGINX`.
  Streaming should work out of the box on `Rainbows`.

Hope it will work

For more consider [Rails  streaming](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb)

Comment: Thanks but it's not related to the web server. I did all that with Unicorn to get `render stream: true` working. It's the global `stream` in ApplicationController - to make it the default option - that doesn't work. It's throwing an exception, which wouldn't happen because of the app server being used.